# Should users be able to receive reputation by having accepted edits?

Tags: feature-request

Some users are putting a lot of time and effort into making edits on this site. Would it be possible to reward these people that are fixing questions by awarding them with reputation?

The could be two ways of rewarding the user, a percentage of reputation that the question receives (for example 5% for a question that has 10 up-votes gives you 5 reputation), or a flat rate (for example 3 reputation)?

Maybe it would be good to have an up-vote choice in the edit review section where the reviewer can up-vote the edit to give the user reputation. By having the up-vote option, it would reward users for higher-quality edits compared to a two word edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a reward for having accepted edits. For example, on a post [you recently submitted an edit to](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/revisions/101659/4), I approved your edit and made some additional edits. When I approved your edit, you received two reputation for successfully submitting an edit:

[image]

You can learn more about how to get reputation on [this help page](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

If you'd like to suggest an alternative to the two point reward already in place, that would be a network wide change and should be posted to [the network wide meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

However, I think some kind of percentage based system would be a bad idea. It would encourage people to make unnecessary edits to posts they think will be popular, or posts that are already popular.